# Is there anyway to change title of OpenFileDialog in Silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, openfiledialog

I'm using OpenFileDialog in a Silverlight 3 application (sample code below).

```
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = false;            
        dialog.Filter = "XML Schemas (*.xsd)|*.xsd";
        dialog.ShowDialog();
```

It was a surprise to me that there's no such property like 'Title' to define Title of the dialog. So I wonder if there's a workaround allowing to set custom title for this dialog.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no work around (in SL4 either).

Microsoft seem to have taken the approach (one that I think is quite sensible) of keeping APIs to this sort of sensitve thing (it allows access to the host system) to barest minimum.

It would seem that within controlled limits the SL Team will relax some of these limitations after careful examination **when** there is a demand.