# How to style open file dialog box in Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, dialog

I am not an SL developer myself, but before I invest in it, I want to make sure I get its capabilities and limitations. My question is is it possible to style (i.e. change the UI of) an open file dialog box? It would be nice to see a sample if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that. You have no chance to change the title, or preset a path either.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog(v=vs.95).aspx, [Is there anyway to change title of OpenFileDialog in Silverlight 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637135/is-there-anyway-to-change-title-of-openfiledialog-in-silverlight-3))

Comment: This is correct - the OpenFileDialog is the provided by the host Operating System, so it looks familiar to users of that OS.